# Visual Studio's default browser will not change from Internet Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, default

I've tried the browse with... method and went into Chrome to make it my default. VS says Chrome is my default, but no matter what I try to do, it opens a new window in IE.

VS 2008, IE8

How do I make it open a window in Chrome?!

EDIT:: Just uninstalled IE8, and now it opens in Chrome, but it gives me an error when I compile.

> Unable to start program
>
> 'http://localhost:49388/Dealership/Default.aspx'.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.

I just can't win. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the port... sometimes the port changes one or two digits between the Web Development Server's url and the chrome url

Comment: The port is the same. I set IE as default with rightclick ->browse with... and no error. Then switched back to Chrome and there was an error but the address along with the port were identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just making a new project, and the error went away.